# Windows 10 CU - i7 3770K always on max frequency

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, intel-core-i7

I've an issue in windows 10 creators update. My CPU 3770K runs always on max frequency 3.9ghz in idle with low CPU percentage of usage. With windows 7, the CPU freq. swing between 1.6ghz (idle) and 3.9ghz (load). I would like to restore the previous behaviour.

Some detail:

- Windows 10 Creators Update, all update available are installed
- all mb drivers are updated
- The power preset is "high performace" with  minimum level of cpu 1%, max 100%
- Turbo boost enabled
- CPU freq settings on BIOS is set to "auto"
- C1E enabled
- EIST enabled

I use a MSI z77-g43 with the last BIOS.

Anyone can help me? 
thanks

Comment: Why are you concerned about the frequency of your CPU running at 3.9 GHz instead of 1.6 GHz, the fact it was running at 1.6 GHz indicates, the CPU in the past was being down throttled.  Frequency of your CPU has very little to do with your CPU usage.   Most people would want their 3.5 GHz CPU to run at 3.9 GHz all the time its more efficient.

Comment: "high performance" this is the cause. set the power plan so balanced

Comment: @magicandre1981 Change power plan doesn't change anything. I tried several times but it seems that the system ignores that settings.

Comment: @Ramhound I prefer than the system changes the frequency in base at the real CPU demand and tasks power demand. Most of the time I have a low % of CPU usage and because it's summer, I prefer lower CPU temperatures.

Comment: @AlessandroCorradini - Switch your power plan to something other then performance if that is the case.  "high performance" is going to attempt to boost your CPU, when it's possible, which per your description no thermal thorottling is happening.